# Copy XML Nodes with an Iteration

Tags: xml, xslt, iteration

I've got a question about copying some xml, with xslt.

I have xml that sometimes contains Parent nodes with an iteration. They look like this.

```
<opdracht iteration="1">
         <a> 1 </a>
         <b> 1 </b>
</opdracht>
<opdracht iteration="2">
         <a> 1 </a>
         <b> 1 </b>
</opdracht>
<opdracht iteration="3">
         <a> 1 </a>
         <b> 1 </b>
</opdracht>
```

If i choose 3 items, the xml will build 3 iterated nodes. But if I choose 5 of 6 items, it generates 5 or 6 different xml iterations.

I need to make some XSLT that allows me to copy these parent and child Iterated nodes, for as long as they are iterated. And output them under the same original name. So :

```
<opdracht iteration="1"> Becomes <opdracht>
And
<opdracht iteration="2"> becomes also <opdracht>
```

And so forth....

How do I do this?

Comment: Your question in unclear. Simplify your input XML and specify what output you want to obtain. That'll make your question less vague.

Comment: I hope the question is clear now?

Comment: Alas, it isn't, at least not to me. At the core of the confusion lies your use of *iteration* and *iterated*, terms that do have a meaning in computer science but appear not to make any sense in the context you're using them for. Confusion ensues. - Reducing the XML verbosity is definitely a step in the right direction. Could be improved by making it into a complete doc that can be copied and pasted, making it easy for people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question, but I "think" you are saying you want to copy the XML, but remove the **@iteration** attribute from the **opdracht** elements.

If that is the case, you can do it with a simple extension to the XSLT **identity transform**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="opdracht/@iteration" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following XML

```
<root>
<opdracht iteration="1"> 
         <a> 1 </a> 
         <b> 1 </b> 
</opdracht> 
<opdracht iteration="2"> 
         <a> 1 </a> 
         <b> 1 </b> 
</opdracht> 
<opdracht iteration="3"> 
         <a> 1 </a> 
         <b> 1 </b> 
</opdracht> 
</root>
```

The following is output:

```
<root>
  <opdracht>
    <a> 1 </a>
    <b> 1 </b>
  </opdracht>
  <opdracht>
    <a> 1 </a>
    <b> 1 </b>
  </opdracht>
  <opdracht>
    <a> 1 </a>
    <b> 1 </b>
  </opdracht>
</root>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I mean. I'm really sorry for the confusion I'm bringing to the table, but my english is not my strongest point, and I am very new to XSLT. I think this will solve my problem